# Display JSX code from a JSON data in Reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a JSON which contains JSX code i.e

```
var data = {"content":"<ul className='list-group'><li className='list-group-item' onClick={this.svgMapClicked}>Name: Firmino</li><li className='list-group-item' >Goals: 22</li></ul>"}
```

In my Component, first I import the JSON i.e

```
import data from './data.json';
```

Then I have

```
this.state = {footy: data}
```

Now in my render function, I want to display it like but get the content from the JSON data:

```
render() {<div><ul className='list-group'><li className='list-group-item' onClick={this.svgMapClicked}>Name: Firmino</li><li className='list-group-item' >Goals: 22</li></ul></div>};
```

So, here is my render function:

```
render(){<div>{this.state.footy.content}</div>};
```

Instead of the JSX tag, {this.state.footy.content} is displayed as a string. I have searched for similar issue but I was unable to find.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the content HTML in json, you should store the data and create the content in JSX like

```
var data = [
  {name: 'Firmino', goals: 22}
];

this.state = {footy: data}
```

and in render

```
render() {
   return <div>
      <ul className='list-group'>
      {this.state.footy.map((player) => {
          return <React.Fragment>
               <li className='list-group-item' onClick={() => this.svgMapClicked(player)}>Name: {player.name}</li>
               <li className='list-group-item' >Goals: {player.goals}</li>
          </React.Fragment>
      })}
      </ul>
   </div>
 };
```

If you absolutely need to render the HTML then, you could use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like

```
render() {
   return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html : this.state.footy} } />};
```

Comment: I am aware of both the techniques that you have suggested. In fact I have also tried [Interweave](https://github.com/milesj/interweave) to render HTML without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Well none of them served my exact purpose(which is to render the JSX content from the JSON, *can't use Html as we can't add event handlers of React like onClick). By using Interweave or dangerouslySetInnerHtml, I am able to render the html but I also want to add event handlers like onClick. We can achieve it by using jquery but I don't feel that's a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work quite well. Just learnt, or re-learnt, it.

- Convert data.json to data.jsx
- Use a static json **of** jsx, which can be used in any jsx

[image]